# Looking up values in one table and outputting it into another using join/awk

Tags: text-processing, awk, join

Table 1 (tab separated):

```
NC_000001.11 1243 A T 0.14 
NC_000005.11 1432 G C 0.0006 
NC_000012.12 1284 A T 0.93428 
NC_000021.9 9824 T C 0.9
```

Lookup table (tab separated) - this is in fact huge, around 6G gzipped:

```
 NC_000001.11 1243 rs73647921 A   T  
 NC_000005.11 1432 rs75444    G   C
 NC_000012.12 1284 rs754723 A T  
 NC_000021.9 9824 rs865545  T C
```

I would like the output to match on the first 4 columns of table 1 which correspond to columns 1/2/4/5 of the lookup table; taking table 1 and transforming it into:

```
MarkerName P-Value
rs73647921 0.14
rs75444    0.0006
rs754723 0.93428 
rs865545  0.9
```

I think I need to use join along the lines of:

```
join -t, -a 1 -a 2 -o0,1.5,2.3 -e ' -' file1 file2
```

But this doesn't seem to work. How could I also use a gzipped file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With awk (and bash) you can write

```c
awk '
    BEGIN {FS = OFS = "\t"}
    NR == FNR {pvalue[$1,$2,$3,$4] = $5; next}
    FNR == 1 {print "MarkerName", "P-Value"}
    { key = $1 SUBSEP $2 SUBSEP $4 SUBSEP $5
      sub(/\r$/, "", key)
    }
    key in pvalue {print $3, pvalue[key]}
' table1.tsv <(zcat lookup.tsv.gz)
```

awk uses the SUBSEP variable to join comma-separated indices for arrays.

That last bit of syntax around the zcat is a bash [Process Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution)

For multi-field join conditions, `join` can be painful to work with. It also complains if the files are not sorted.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to offer a solution. When running this I get an empty file as the output with just "MarkerName", "P-Value" as a header?

Comment: Your input files may have `\r\n` line endings, in which case $5 of the lookup file might be `T\r` not just `T`, so the key would never be in the array.

Comment: ok thanks, so I should try and reformat this file?

Comment: Try this edit..

Comment: sorry I get:     bash: syntax error near unexpected token ')'

Comment: If I cut and paste this exact command in bash, I get no such error (although on macos I do need to use gzcat instead of zcat)

Comment: worked, sorry was being an idiot. Many thanks!

Answer (score 3):

have you tried .. ?

```
join -o 2.3,1.5 f1 <(zcat f2.gz )
```

by default `join` use first field. (and `-1 x -2 x` is equivalent to `-j x` , and `-j 1` is equivalent to `" "` )

I assume

- file are sorted,
- key is first field only.

---

to sort on all fields

```
join -o 2.2,1.2 \
    <(awk '{printf "%s %s\n",$1 $2 $3 $4,$5}' f1) \
    <(zcat f2.gz| awk '{printf "%s %s\n",$1 $2 $4 $5,$3}' )
```

where

- using two `awk` to pipe to `join` might not be a good idea (altough this might save memory compared to an `awk` only solution),
- `awk` command build an index from revelant fields,
- `zcat` used to ungzip,
- this leave `0`'s problem open.

Comment: Will this match  the first 4 columns of table 1 which correspond to columns 1/2/4/5 of the lookup table?

Comment: @tacrolimus, the longer solution under "to sort on all fields" does, yes.

Comment: @Archemar A potential for false matches: suppose `abc11 234` is in f1 and `abc1 1234` is in f2 -- you might want to join the fields with a separator.